# Xamarin/Android: F# scoping - how do I see a namespace in a different file?

Tags: android, f#, xamarin.android, xamarin

Xamarin/Android: F# scoping - how do I see a namespace in a different file?

I know this sounds really basic, but I can't seem to get it to work. I will illustrate with an example:

I start a new solution, I select a new F# Android App and call it FSScopeTest1, giving me MainActivity.fs

```
namespace FSScopeTest1
open System
open Android.Content
open Android.OS
open Android.Runtime
open Android.Views
open Adroid.Widget

[<Activity (Label = "FSScopeTest1", MainLauncher = true)>]
type MainActivity () =
    inherit Activity ()
    let mutable count:int = 1
    override this.OnCreate (bundle) =
        base.OnCreate (bundle)
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        this.SetContentView (Resource_Layout.Main)
        // Get our button from the layout resource, and attach an event to it
        let button = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource_Id.myButton)
        button.Click.Add (fun args ->
            button.Text <- sprintf "%d clicks" count
            count <- count + 1
        )
```

I then add a new F# Source file, ScopeTestNS.fs

```
namespace ScopeTestNS

module ScopeTestMod =
    let astr = "some text"
```

I then add to MainActivity.fs, on the second line:

```
open ScopeTestNS
```

and change the lamba expression for button.Click.Add to read

```
        button.Click.Add (fun args ->
            // button.Text <- sprintf "%d clicks!" count
            // count <- count + 1
            button.Text <- ScopeTestMod.astr
        )
```

now, when I build the solution, I get the error:

```
The namespace or module "ScopeTestMod" is not defined.
```

How do I make my namespace ScopeTestNS visible in MainActivity.fs so I can see any modules I define there?

Many thanks,
Ross

Comment: Are the files in the correct order - The ScopeTestNs file needs to be included before the other file.

Comment: To amplify on @JohnPalmer's remarks; you need to manually change the compile order in the .fsproj file.  This is a known issue with the F# binding. https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/135

Comment: And to be even more specific, "manual" here means open the fsproj file in a text editor.  There's an ordering thing somewhere in a options menu (that looks kind of manual); don't bother with it.

Answer (score 5):

The f# compiler reads the source files in a specific order (unlike the c# compiler).  You need to ensure that your project has included the files in the correct order so that you can access modules defined in other files.

**EDIT** based on comment from Onorio Catenacci:

Apparently the F# binding used in Xamarin Studio does not currently support reordering of files in a F# project (see this github issue https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/135).  However, .fsproj files are simple xml files which can be edited with a text editor to change the order in which files are compiled.

**EDIT EDIT**

Apparently the F# addin in xamarin studio does now allow for drag and drop to reorder files (thanks to @7sharp9 for the update)

Comment: Old answer, but just to note that the F# addin does now let you reorder the files via drag and drop in Xamarin Studio.